# HTTP Status 500 - JDBC rollback failed using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, session

I have a java application using Hibernate and tomcat server.my app is working fine for hours.Then is stop working..showing the following error.I have no idea what is happening and i m really new to hibernate technology.I read something about c3p0 lib but i dont know exacly how is working..

```
HTTP Status 500 - JDBC rollback failed

type Exception report

message JDBC rollback failed

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:200)
    com.javawebtutor.service.LoginService.getUserByUserId(LoginService.java:37)
    com.javawebtutor.service.LoginService.authenticateUser(LoginService.java:17)
    com.javawebtutor.controller.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1251)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1243)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4723)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:213)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192)
    com.javawebtutor.service.LoginService.getUserByUserId(LoginService.java:37)
    com.javawebtutor.service.LoginService.authenticateUser(LoginService.java:17)
    com.javawebtutor.controller.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 33,669,634 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 6 milliseconds ago.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3589)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3478)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4019)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:890)
    com.javawebtutor.service.LoginService.getUserByUserId(LoginService.java:33)
    com.javawebtutor.service.LoginService.authenticateUser(LoginService.java:17)
    com.javawebtutor.controller.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3039)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3489)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3478)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4019)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:890)
    com.javawebtutor.service.LoginService.getUserByUserId(LoginService.java:33)
    com.javawebtutor.service.LoginService.authenticateUser(LoginService.java:17)
    com.javawebtutor.controller.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.50 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.50
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml is

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">dbusername</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">dbpass</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>      



        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>




        <mapping class="com.javawebtutor.model.User" />
         <mapping class="com.javawebtutor.model.Questionaire" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please help..

Comment: The root cause tells you what happened: `connection was unexpectedly lost.`.

Comment: ok but why that is happening..

Comment: Which version of the MySQL Connector used?

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar

Comment: Well I wouldn't know why that happens. It was unexpected after all.

Comment: @Ilias Zampetakis It seems that something wrong with your server. Client can't retrieve bytes from InputStream, because they are not available. Method read() of the abstract InputStream class returns value -1. It leads to EOFException in readFully() method of the com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO class (class used to communicate with MySQL Server). So you need to check your MySQL server status and configuration (possibly access settings) or connection with server if it is on another machine.